# How to stop or divert current flowing in live conductor without switching off?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electrons, electrical-resistance

One day I was wondering of changing my fan regulator (switch).

Then I thought if I change the switch then what will happen if someone switch ON the main switch. Then it might be possible I will be electrocuted!!

Then I was thinking about this device, in which we can insert the live wire (or any kind of wire) and it can create some kind of FIELD which would block the electric current. And we block the electric in that line without disturbing any other device on other connected wiring.

Imagine that you can work on a live wire not getting electrocuted without wearing safety measures!

My question is how I can build a device something like this?
What will be the requirements and what will be calculation needed to start building this device?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think this question is better suited for the Home Improvement or Electrical Engineering. Secondly, the standard procedure for working on something like this is lockout-tagout. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockout-tagout . You should put a lock on the breaker box with a sign indicating that work is being done, and that the breakers can't be accessed for safety reasons.

As far as implementing what you're talking about, you would bypass the section of the circuit that you are working on by shorting it out, not try to insert something into the circuit that would produce a back EMF like an inductor (which would only slow the build of current anyway). Not only is this not really practical, it's also easy to make a mistake with, and the consequence can be death. So you really need to lock the breaker box if there are other people around that may mess with it. Please be safe.

Comment: Not practical? Why? Am I thinking on wrong side?

Comment: I mean that safely and correctly implementing something like you propose is less practical than just locking up your breaker box. This (and many others) is the reason that lockout-tagout is the industry standard of electricians. They are fully aware of how a circuit can be bypassed, but it is far simpler and safer to just prevent the wires from being hot in the first place.